# updating existing records with a unique integer

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, unique, generate-series

I have an existing table with records in it and I've just added a new column `ver` which I would like to be unique.

```
create table foo (
  bar text,
  ver integer
);

select * from foo;

bar   ver
---   ---
one   null
two   null
three null
```

I'm struggling with how to do this for some reason.

I want to do something like:

```
update foo set ver = ( select generate_series(1, 1000) );
```

or maybe

```
update foo set ver = v from (select generate_series(1, 1000) as v );
```

...but of course neither of those work.  Can anyone point out the obvious for me?

Comment: If you want that to be unique for future rows as well, then use a sequence

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- no, I don't need (or want) that.  I just need to ensure that the existing records become unique. (In the my actual code I'm writing an SQL migration that could be applied to a production database: add the column, fill the column, add a unique index.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a primary key (or a unique column) to individually update rows of a table. In the lack of such a column you can use the hidden column `ctid` which is unique by definition, example:

```
update foo f
set ver = rn
from (
    select ctid, row_number() over (order by ctid) as rn
    from foo
    ) s
where f.ctid = s.ctid
```

Comment: Well, that certainly works, but I think it will take me a while to understand why...  in fact my real table does have a unique id and I've currently solved the problem with `update foo set ver = id;` -- but I can't believe that that's the only or best solution!

Comment: You can use `id` instead of `ctid`. The solution gives consecuttive numbers starting from 1. Of course, a simple assigning `id` is the best option if it meets all your requirements.

Comment: Tick.  This is the neatest answer and it's very clever. (Does it worry anyone else that we have to resort to this level of cleverness, though?)

Answer (score 1):

Use some PL/pgSQL code:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   c CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM foo;
   x foo;
   i integer := 1;
BEGIN
   OPEN c;
   LOOP
      FETCH c INTO x;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
      UPDATE foo SET ver = i WHERE CURRENT OF c;
      i := i + 1;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Then you can add a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD UNIQUE(ver);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a sequence.

```
 create sequence foo_ver;
```

then add the column with a default value of the next number in the sequence.

```
 alter table foo add ver integer default nextval('foo_ver') not null;
```

data is auto-populated, and new records will automatically get a new, unique number.

Optional: create unique index to be sure.

```
 create unique index on foo(ver);
```

Comment: I have already said that I specifically do not want to do that.  Going forward, this column will not be a simple sequence. It will be filled by the application. I just need a way to populate the existing records -- as I said in the comments to the question.

Comment: Question: Why don't you need new records to also be unique?

Comment: For more information, please re-read my original comment to your answer.  ;)

Comment: This solution should work for that, as if you provide the ver column during insert, it will not use the sequence. As an added measure, if you want, you can change the default value  for ver (or remove it) and drop the sequence if you want. This is just a quick way